# Using Drupal Views VS templating

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-templates

I have recently started working with Drupal on the side and have had to tackle the limitations I come up against in the Views API. More than not I find it faster and more powerful to code it myself.

1. It is hard to create custom views that have a specific look and feel without create custom files anyway.
2. Creating the pages from scratch in a *.tpl.php gives me more choice and flexibility. I have done a couple of them now and it is almost as fast.

For a developer (since this is a programming forum) what is better in your opinion:
**Views** or **Custom templates?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not even sure what you mean by custom templates (please say you're not hardcoding SQL into .tpl.php files), but no matter what you mean, the answer is to **use Views wherever possible**.

**Reasons:**

- **Development speed** - I promise you creating a View will be faster than a custom module 99.9% of the time
- **Stability** - it has hundreds of thousands of testers
- **Security** - it has the eyes of many on its code
- **Support** - there are hundreds of contrib modules that interact with Views somehow
- **Maintenance** - Views is a Drupal standard. Using custom modules gives your site's maintenance an unnecessary learning curve.
- **Upgrading** - Views will provide an upgrade path from D6 to D7. Your custom stuff won't.

As for your "it is hard to create custom views that have a specific look and feel" point, I think you'll change your mind after a little time with template_preprocess_whatever() functions and overriding Views templates. You have absolute control if you want it.

Comment: To clarify what I mean is simply that I cannot do what I would like to in views. It's not flexible enough and requires a lot of learning in the beginning. And I'm not talking about creating modules, simply replacing certain nodes and elements in the page with tpl.php files - I guess you call it theme, although for me it comes down to functionality.

Comment: @WmasterJ, I still don't understand the problem. Views can handle 99% of tasks that involve listing things, and it requires less learning than writing it yourself.

Comment: I will take your and other peoples word on this and try to get onboard with Views more. Need to learn what the template_preprocess_x() functions will do for me. Thanks for the feedback.